Didn't receive USDB after swap through OKX Wallet — what to do?
I have a problem. It seems that I lost crypto when swapping through OKX Web3 Wallet (iOS) via OKX DEX. I swapped ANDY for USDB on the Blast network (txhash: 0xef241e1aa12dfa5fee23e5508549031e824c92a972e6bbe4d43e114851ff85b7) and was waiting for the USDB to show up in my balance.
However, I never received the USDB. When I checked the transaction history, I saw an unknown contract interaction with an address I don’t recognize (txhash: 0x715c6bdd6da71ebb58fba2ecb7065b6215086d74a91fd7a3aa2515ae9a6d78c0).
Were my funds stolen? Or what could be the problem? No one has access to my private key. This crypto was stored in the wallet for a long time without any issues. Is there anything I can do to recover my funds? The crypto still seems to be in this smart contract.

It is odd that the second transaction is just 10 seconds after the first one, and it is executed from a contract. Did you create the address 0x371381143...? do you have its mnemonic or the private key?
